# what is the way to reduce the size of image without reducing height and width in codeigniter?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

I'm trying to create image upload functionality in Codeigniter. While uploading a file I want to maintain the height and width but the size should be reduced for example from 10kb to 5 kb.

The below code is working fine, the file is getting uploaded but the size is the same.
what changes can be done to make it correct

```
        if($_FILES['logo']['name'] != '')
        {

            $getimagesize  = getimagesize($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name']);
            $w = $getimagesize[0];
            $h = $getimagesize[1];
            #NEW CODE
            $config['upload_path'] = './upload/'; 
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('logo'))
            {
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            }#EOF if(!$this->upload->do_upload('logo'))
            else
            {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                $config = [
                    'image_library' => 'gd',
                    'source_image' => './upload/'.$data['file_name'],
                    'create_thumb' => FALSE,
                    'maintain_ratio' => FALSE,
                    'quality' => '60',
                    'height' => $h,
                    'width' => $w,
                    'new_image' => './upload/'.$data['file_name']
                ];
                $this->load->library('image_lib',$config);
                if($this->image_lib->resize())
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success','image saved');
                    redirect('welcome/school_details');
                }
                #Adding data into databse


            }
```

Comment: Use php built-in functions like [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) and set quality.

Comment: FYI There is no real reason to get and set the image dimensions if you aren't changing them.

Comment: @alex that's not the issue. every time the file is uploaded with the changed name.

Comment: @Yahya: I'm trying to do it with imagecreatefromjpeg function but is it giving error. It is not opening folder via HTTP as giving error.

Comment: http://blog.clonesinfo.com/how-to-reduce-compress-image-file-size-uploading-using-php-code/

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

Change config upload:

```
'quality' => '60'
```

to

```
'quality' => '60%'
```

Comment: It is the same. No change in the file size

Comment: Indeed it's the only issue I see. Delete the uploaded image and try again, maybe it's not overwriting from your previous tests.

Comment: @alex that's not the issue. every time the file is uploaded with the changed name.